# Pull, rebase, push, in one command (or just a few)

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase

When using Git, I often find myself doing the following when working in `master`:

```
# work work work...
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git commit -a -m 'more work done'
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
# turns out master was updated since my previous pull
$ git checkout temp
# I don't want a merge commit for a simple bugfix
$ git rebase master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge temp
$ git push origin master
$ git branch -d temp
```

... and I get tired of doing this. Is there a way to do this dance without all of the checkouts, and preferably without (manually) creating the temporary branch?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you don't mind not creating a branch called `temp`, you could just do the following all on `master`:

```
git commit -a -m 'more work done'
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

... or equivalently:

```
git commit -a -m 'more work done'
git pull --rebase origin master
```

If you do want to keep the `temp` branch, however, you can still make this a bit shorter by not checking out `master` just to do the `pull` - you only need to `fetch` and then rebase your branch onto `origin/master`:

```
# work work work...
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git commit -a -m 'more work done'
$ git fetch origin
# It looks like origin/master was updated, so:
$ git rebase origin/master
# Then when you finally want to merge:
$ git checkout master
$ git merge temp
$ git push origin master
$ git branch -d temp
```

[sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555800/pull-rebase-push-in-one-command-or-just-a-few/7555878#7555878) reminds me that you could replace:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase origin/master
```

... with:

```
$ git pull --rebase origin master
```

... which is *nearly* equivalent.  The difference is that when you run `git fetch origin`, all of your remote-tracking branches for `origin` will be updated, whereas when you pull a particular branch from `origin`, none of them are - it's just the temporary ref `FETCH_HEAD` that is updated.  I personally prefer running one extra command (`git fetch origin`), and seeing all the remote branches that have changed in the output.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about the `--rebase` option, it seems to fit my workflow perfectly.

Comment: Work great for me! By the way, how can we ignore `unstaged/uncommitted changes`?

Answer (score 10):

You can at least optimize the rebasing: [`git pull --rebase`](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html)

I'm not exactly sure how you like things, but I like my workflow sort of like this:

```
git checkout -b temp
git commit -a -m 'more work done'
git pull --rebase origin master
```

That way I keep my focus on the branch at hand.

Then later, I do

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge temp
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull --rebase --autostash origin staging && git push origin staging;
```